# How to create words construction

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, construction

I am trying to create some words construction using custom template, for example I need something like this:

[image: example]

and I don't really know best way to doing this, I want to create labels rotate and place it same as image looks like, but I am sure it is bad idea. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Please define "something like this:" in a logic way: What are your constraint? Who chooses if the word is written in horizontal or in vertical, if it's the algorithms, on what grounds? who choose the colors, if it's the algorythms, on what ground? Who choose the textSize, if it's the algorythms, on what grounds? This image you're showing are likely be put together by a designer with an artistic perspective. Computer cannot do art. They take constraint based decision, and they are very good at it if the constraints are well defined.

Comment: @FlorianBurel this is just example, words color is not so important, you have string array and you want create the same template, one by one this words should be placed into the view, the font size and word length will depend from place they are placed on, I haven't algorithm yet I just want to know if there have some ways to doing it, if it possible

Comment: It is very possible. Those are just label drawn at certain point and on for the vertical one, a their transform property has been changed to be rotated by (M_PI / 2.). Drawing the world is not challenging. What is if finding how to fit each words next to the other. I'll suppose you'll feed the view a list of words, then based on that we will have to write an algorythms that divise your space on rectangle and have words drawn in it. I would start by the simple stuff.. Create a UIView subclass that takes a list of words and print them on 2 colums...

Comment: @FlorianBurel yes, it was my idea, thank you for the heads-up! I will try this way.